# Is it possible to use one user defined function in another function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Suppose that I have defined a function called `mystep` and I have saved it as an `.m` file. Is it possible to use this function in another function? For example:

```
function [OutPuts] = NewFunc[Inputs]

[Some codes]

[~] = mystep(something)

[Some Codes]

end
```

Comment: Yes, of course, calling a user-defined function from within another function is possible. You don't need to declare both in the same file. What's the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, functions not matching the filename [are called local functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) and only visible within the file.